# Name of the company on the same level as navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

I'm not able to format the name of the restaurant "al dente" in the navbar. I'm trying to have the same format for everything. Please note that I started coding yesterday..

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
#navbar {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  }
.navbarlist {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">Al Dente
<nav>
    <ul >
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>  
</div>
```

Comment: It's easy to do so. Wrap "Al Dente" inside a <span> and apply float:left on the span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - congratulations on starting to code. The trick to get everything on the same line is to use flex (there are other ways of dooing it - but that is hte current - best practise and you should start out with the best in mine.

First thing to know about flex - is that when you apply the "dsiaply:flex styling - it only affects the direct children of the element - so what we ned to do is to wrap you "al dente" in an element - and that is uually a h1 in this case - since it is hte name of thepage  / highst order heading.

So - the things I changes / added

- wrapper the name with a h1 and gave the h1 some styling
- modified the #navbar to have equal padding left and right
- added `display: flex` to the #navbar to allow the inline / flex layout which will affect only the h1 and the navlist
- added `align-items: center` to enure that the heading and the nav list are vertically alinged into the navbar
- added the `justify-content: space-between` to ensure that the heading and nav list are on either side of the navbar.
- removed the float on the navlist li's

I would recommend changing the color of thelinks - blue on black is not very good for contrast (it is heard to read).

spend some time learnning the subtleties of flexbox styling - it will absolutely help you in developing forward looking code and styling.

Welcome to the coding world :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  
.navbarlist {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
 <h1>Al Dente</h1>
 <nav>
    <ul >
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="navbarlist"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>  
</div>
```